# How can I print every values of each attributes of a class in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

I want to print each values of a class, but I don't know how to do it. I understand why my method of doing it doesn't work though.

```py
class test:
    def __init__(self, a = 1, b = 2, c = 3):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c

classobject = test()

for attr in dir(classobject) :
    if not attr.startswith('__'):
        print(str(attr) + ' value= ' + classobject.attr)
```

I get the error `AttributeError: 'test' object has no attribute 'attr'`

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`classobject.attr` is specifically looking for an attribute named `attr` in `classobject`.

`attr` does not get magically replaced at runtime by the appropriate value.

What you need is the [getattr](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr) function:

```
print(str(attr) + ' value= ' + getattr(classobject, attr))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```
print(test.__dict__)
```

Which will basically scrape out *all* the attributes of an object. This may or may not be what you want but it is at least a superset of what you want. I suppose you could filter by keys if you have a list of attributes you explicitly care about.

Answer (score 0):

```
classobject = test()
attrs = vars(classobject)
for key,value in attrs.items():
    print (str(key) + ' value= ' +str(value))
```

result:

a value= 1

b value= 2

c value= 3